# How do I put div after div with fixed position?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I'm trying to create a front page in which i am using something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>My Page</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">

    <h1>Header</h1>
    <br/>
</div>
<div id="box1">
Content
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>`enter code here`
```

And my css is

```
#header{
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  margin-left:0%;
  color:#FEA13A;
  text-shadow:#CCC 1px 1px 1px;
  font-size:22px;
  background:#000000;
}

#box1{
  width:80%;
  position:relative;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left:20%;
  margin-right:20;
}


#wrapper{
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
```

I want to be able to use fixed position in every part of the page to adjust to the screen but when I use "position:fixed;" on the first header, everything after it doesn't take the positioning properly.

How to solve this?

Comment: _"I want to be able to use fixed position in every part of the page to adjust to the screen"._ Probably a bad idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "everything after it doesn't take the positioning properly"?  When you define an object as having a fixed position, it is basically ignore when positioning everything that comes after it (basic CSS).  In advanced CSS structures, this varies, but you are using VERY basic applications.  If you set the "header" `DIV` to `position: fixed;`, then the "box1" `DIV` will render as if the "header" `DIV` was never there (and "box1" appears on top of "header" with position from the body).  Set a fixed position to both and define the location of the "box1".

Comment: ok, then I understand that there can't be a position div after a "fixed" div, I got it, then how do I place div after div with proper positions? Should I like use "header absolute, then box1 relative and box2 relative" or what?

Comment: I'm not really grasping what it is that you are wanting to do.  Please explain what it is you want to accomplish (ie. "header to be positions are x,y with box1 immediate below and box2 to the right of box1).

Comment: I want to create a page with a header, and content, but I want to be able to use the position property in each thing, but if I use "fixed" all things show in header, I want to be able to be able to show them after the other one. like this.....  HEADER, BOX1, BOX2, BOX3, FOOTER. how do I apply "position:x" to all of them without ruining the code, because when I apply it it shows all of things in header, do I have to apply something to the body or what?

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/y2gd0fe6/?  This uses fixed position on all elements to position them EXACTLY where you tell them to be.  It isn't a particularly good thing to use fixed positioning due to complexities with browser rendering, OS rendering, and screen resolutions.  Most would use a relative positioning system, it is significantly more flexible.

Comment: exactly that is just what I wanted to do. thanks a lot

Comment: No problem.  Just remember, this is a highly frowned upon method of positioning, and I HIGHLY recommend looking into relative positioning instead.